# Solving "Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream" server-side

Tags: .net, apache, xampp, httprequest, .net-2.0

I am facing this error while I am trying to connect the server:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

I have gone through all previous questions and answers. However, I can not change the code. the program was working correctly until some update or problem happened on the server.

The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 running XAMPP Version: 1.8.3

The program was developed under .NET Framework 2.0

How can I solve this problem from server side ? The server is under my control and I have full access to it.

**Edit:**
I doubled check the server. The windows update is off. I am very confused about what exactly happened to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```